# How to display the request sent time and the response received time in Fiddler?

Tags: web, request, response, fiddler

I'm working with Fiddler Web Debugger tool version 4.4.4.8.

I've made a request to e.g. www.google.com and fiddler shows that a request is sent and the response is received.

How could I know about and display when the request was sent and when the response is received? start/end dates are not in the left columns in Fiddler.

Is there any setting?

I saw there are some Timers: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/timers

How to display/use them?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your simplest approach would be to right-click the Web Sessions list's column headers and choose `Customize Columns...` from the menu.

From the `Collection` dropdown, choose the `Session Timers` option and then select the timer of interest in the `Timer Name` dropdown.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Tasks/ConfigureColumns#add-custom-columns

Answer (score 41):

If you just need to profile a *single request*, you can view the `Statistics` tab on the right, when clicking on a request in the requests pane like this.

[image: Fiddler response time tab]

If you need to profile *multiple requests*, select multiple requests from the left capture pane and you'll see the aggregate performance under `statistics` tab.

[image: Fiddler aggregate response tab]

Comment: You can also add the Overall_Elapsed column.

Answer (score 16):

> Pick new new column and go as per the screenshot below and you are
>   done in new Column.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For Fiddler 4.6.2, Right Click on any of the Column Headers on the Sessions pane.

Customize Columns > Collection > SessionTimers > ClientBeginRequest and ClientDoneRequest

It appears like this.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't ServerBeginRequest and ServerDoneResponse be the columns to use?

Comment: @Hutch I suppose that would depend whether you're interested in server performance vs user experience

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Fiddler Everywhere v1.5.1**

Click the vertical ellipsis on a column, then click "Columns", then check the Time, Date, and/or Duration Columns.

[image: Fiddle Everywhere: Edit Columns]